# App crashes on Screenlock despite on_pause function

Tags: android, crash, kivy

My android app made with Kivy always crashes, when the screen gets locked.

The `on_pause` and `on_resume` functions are implemented and work fine as long as I am just witching between different apps. Also, Kivy is up to date.

Is there anything else I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you would provide more information about the crash or show some code that might be involved.

Maybe check Logcat for any issues, or try to debug your app using the features in your IDE.
Also: onPause() and onResume() only handles the events when your app gets in or out of focus.
Consider implementing onStart() and onStop() too to cover the case if your app is not visible anymore.

You should check out this guide for more information about the android life cycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thx for your fast response. onPause() returns True, onResume() passes. onStart() and onStop() aren't implemented (just passing). When turning off the screen of the mobile device, onPause() and onStop() are called, but later the app crashes and onResume() is not called. Im using Buildozer to build the apk.